# TextView to monitor value

Tags: android, kotlin

Can I make TextView object monitor certain value that is being changed as app is running?

I don't want to keep passing context objects around just so I would be able to call findViewById and then calling the setText() method for TextView object. I want it to react when certain value changes.

I am looking into autofill() method but I am not sure if I am going to find an answer there...

Answer (score 1):

you should try dataBinding,

example -> https://guides.codepath.com/android/Applying-Data-Binding-for-Views

Comment: Thx! I'll take a look.